# Detect existence of physical KVM switch

Tags: powershell, detection

Been trying to do this on my own but with no success...

I'm trying to come up with a script (hopefully PowerShell) that will detect whether my computer is connected through A KVM switch or directly to the screen.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please provide more details, and tell us what you have tried so far. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what's the use-case here? As much as possible, the use of such devices should be transparent.

Comment: "that will detect whether my computer is connected through A KVM switch or directly to the screen." - **that's impossible**: an ideal KVM device will _transparently_ forward raw USB (and PS/2) and DDCI/CI data from the user-end of the KVM to each of the host ends. What you're asking is akin to asking "_are we living in a simulation?_": philosophically unanswerable. - Whereas if you're asking about _imperfect_ KVM devices that incorrectly proxy display and HID data, then that's a different question...

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the monitor information from WMI. There is a WMI class called WmiMonitorID. Then you could then evaluate against the ProductCodeID whether it's the KVM.

```
gcim -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorID | % {if ($_.ProductCodeID -eq "{exampleproductcode}") {write-output "KVM"} Else {write-output "Monitor"}}
```

Comment: i cant get that to work , when i run the command , the objects i get are the pc monitors... (The kvm is not present there...)

Comment: @BenH Someone else bumped this question to the front of StackOverflow last night in a (now deleted) answer (you can't see it as you don't yet have the requisite [10,000 rep to see deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)). I didn't pay attention to the age of the question when I posted my comments.